# Javascript alert not firing up due to new lines added by StringBuilder

Tags: javascript, .net, stringbuilder

I am using `StringBuilder AppendLine` to insert some lines to be shown in a javascript alert box. The alert box is not firing and wehn I see the view source I get the following:

```
alert("Void SendMail(Int32): 
Line number: 0 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
");
```

StringBuilder code:

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: ", frame.GetMethod()));
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Line number: {0} ", frame.GetFileLineNumber()));
sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
```

Please tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: Where's your stringbuilder code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `StringBuilder.ToString()` you should probably use `StringBuilder.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\n")`. This should escape the newlines in the javascript, so the result is:

```
alert("Void SendMail(Int32):\nLine number: 0 \nObject reference not set to an instance of an object.\n");
```

I genuinely hope you're logging the exception somewhere serverside too.

Comment: Yes I am loggin at the server side also. This is just for a handy message for debugging.